# mac install notes

Tags: osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When installing ROS onto MAC I have a couple of notes that might help for anyone in the future when first installing onto MAC.

Firstly perhaps even before you start installing anything. ROS uses BASH so you have to change your terminal program to talk this way.
Start a Terminal, then under the headings select Terminal > Preferences.
Under the Startup Tab change the Shells open with to Command. /bin/bash
Now when you start a new terminal it will start Bash.

Secondly, create youre .bashrc file as normal in your home directory and as the page describes, but you need to make it read it when starting up. In your home directory also create a .bash_profile file and put the following text in it.

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
source ~/.bashrc
fi

this will simply run your .bashrc when it starts up. type "env" and check the details are correct.

I found that I was getting alot of error when trying to install Homebrew, and found that a restart helped after installing the command line tools etc. (Not totally sure of this)

When installing Using brew I found it very useful to use Brew doctor as it pointed to errors. A common one was another script found which I don't think effects anything, despite I am only half way through.

I found that when installing some of the packages such as boost etc. I had to get the non ROS one as it could not find the ROS one, Not sure what was happening here.

For log4cxx it kept saying could not find glibtoolize , this isn't actually a part of glib but is actually a part of libtool, so brew install libtool and that fixes it.

To install swig-wx I followed the following page.
http://ardadv.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/using-ros-robot-operating-system-fuerte.html

and basically did the following..

cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew/swigwx--git
./configure
make
make install

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38606/mac-install-notes../) by [Paul Flick](https://answers.ros.org/users/2823/paul-flick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul Flick](https://answers.ros.org/users/2823/paul-flick/) on 2012-07-11**:
To install the swig-wx I followed this post http://ardadv.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/using-ros-robot-operating-system-fuerte.html  >> cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew/swigwx--git
./configure
make
make install

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2012-07-12**:
This type of information probably fits better on the wiki. The OSX page could definitely use some love: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/OSX. (And, as a Mac user who is sick of dual booting / using a VM, thank you for working on this and documenting it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sorry you guys are having such trouble installing ROS fuerte on OS X, let me just say that things are being worked on.

The reason you have trouble with the Homebrew formulae on github.com/ros/homebrew-fuerte is that those formulae are auto-generated much like the debian distributions are auto generated.  We are currently trying to figure out the best way to provide these OS X specific fixes, like the class name in swig-wx, in a meta data fashion.  So that when new versions of swig-wx are released a new homebrew formulae is automagically generated for the new version and the class name is corrected each time.

I will warn you that because of the way homebrew uses the github api for taps, I cannot branch or create different repository while working on the autogeneration, so the formulae in ros/homebrew-fuerte are subject to change.  I could however create a tag right now so that you have a way to revert to the current formulae if you like.

These changes are creating problems right now, but the hope is that this new system will allow OS X to track changes in the ROS ecosystem faster and better, as well as allowing third parties to distribute stacks for OS X through the ROS release system.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1